# How to do a none interactive pecl install stomp

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to install stomp php extension as part of a Dockerfile.

pecl install has a stomp asking weather to install with openssl extensions, since its all on internal traffic the answer is no so my command looks like

RUN printf "\no" | pecl install stomp

But that doesn't seem to pipe to the prompt, is there any better why of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a backslash in the wrong location. `printf "\no"` prints a linefeed (`\n`) and the letter "o" on a newline. You could do `printf "no\n"`, but at that point, I'd use the more typical `echo no | pecl install stomp`.